# How to execute a server command with vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

short question.

Does anyone know how to execute a server command like "ls -la" with vue.js?

Later it is planned that a button will execute this command.

Comment: what exactly are they listing? vue being a frontend framework should send a request to the server which will handle the request, which you have have to handle'

Comment: I am currently building a Admin Dashboard for my own Server. From that Dashboard i'm planning to execute some kind of workflows (server commands). Like backup a database, or stop a docker container.

Comment: You should create an API for these features in the server side and consume it inside vue.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea :D. Would it make sense to do that for example in python?

Comment: sure. you can use any backend platform.